# How to make instagram login with AWS Cognito Federated Identities

Tags: ios, swift, amazon-web-services, instagram, amazon-cognito

I am trying to implement social media login with AWS Cognito (Mobile services)for iOS app.AWS directly supports login with Amazon, Facebook, Google+ and Twitter.  But i want to implement instagram login with AWS Cognito. How can I achieve this. Please look at the [Screen Shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pKr8S.png), 
In the screen shot you will see provider sections like Amazon,facebook, google and Twitter and the rest of the three are for other. Please let me know which one will work for INSTAGRAM login in rest of the three provider OpenID, SAML and Custom. And how to implement it??

Comment: Did you get any solution for this?

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately there is no out of box support for Instagram, so your best bet is to setup Instagram as Custom provider. Please refer to this [doc](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/developer-authenticated-identities.html) and [blog](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/mobile/integrating-amazon-cognito-using-developer-authenticated-identities-an-end-to-end-example/) to learn about setting up custom provider.

Basically your app needs to interact directly with Instagram to get Instagram User's unique id. That id can then be used as developer user identifier in [GetOpenIdTokenForDeveloperIdentity](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognitoidentity/latest/APIReference/API_GetOpenIdTokenForDeveloperIdentity.html) to get Cognito Identity Id and Token.

Comment: How can I get unique ID for instagram . I am using react-native

Comment: Is there a way I can implement this in cognito hosted UI?

Answer (score 1):

The instagram has stopped supporting authentication. You can use Instagram Basic Display API allows users of your app to get basic profile information, photos, and videos in their Instagram accounts.

Check below links -

1)https://developers.facebook.com/docs/instagram-basic-display-api
2)https://www.instagram.com/developer/

They mentioned, "Authentication — Instagram Basic Display is not an authentication solution. Data returned by the API cannot be used to authenticate your app users or log them into your app. If you need an authentication solution we recommend using Facebook Login instead".

Answer (score -1):

You can take a look at [auth0](https://auth0.com/docs/connections/identity-providers-social), maybe this meet your requirements.